# jQuery datepicker onSelect calling .append() not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to append the selected day to the banner-section of a jQuery datepicker. However, when I have (something like) the following on the datepicker's onSelect I do not see any changes.

```
$(".ui-datepicker-month").append('foo');
```

...however, when I just run this line in the console it works as I expect. Can someone help me understand why?

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardsharp/3b4g0s0v/

Comment: i found what the issue is. i tried running a `console.log($(".ui-datepicker-month").html())`. This gives me the right output too. Notice that even when you delete the a part of the title panel or the entire title panel via inspect element, it returns once you click on a date.
This clearly shows that _datepicker_ seems to recreate the entire title panel on each select **after** the onselect event is called. 

you could either look for an event that is called after the panel is recreated or as a last resort you could use the setTimeout function, which isn't recommended.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane,  ah yes, great, thank you. i'm searching for such an event. but in the meantime setTimeout: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardsharp/3b4g0s0v/5/

Comment: the setTimeout function needs an interval parameter as well that specifies after how much time you need to run the code. in the below example i have given it as 800 since 1 second seemed wayyy too long. You can increase or decrease as you like. 
also i noticed that the .getDate() function gives the date-1, so I added 1 assuming that you want to display the date. 
[http://jsfiddle.net/3b4g0s0v/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/3b4g0s0v/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Well this could be a lot of work but it solves the issue.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3b4g0s0v/8/

I basically add a data attribute to the datepicker using

> $("#datepicker").attr('data-date', (d.getDate() +1));

Then you would need to create 31 css codes as follows:

`#datepicker[data-date="6"] .ui-datepicker-month:after
{
    content: " 6,"
}`

The fiddle provides 6,7 and 8 as a sample. Hope this helps and I also hope you find a simple solution.

**Note:** Personally when I need to use a component such as this with many custom features, I prefer making my own component from scratch. It is lesser work overall. I have made one like datapicker once... it wasn't that hard and provided tons of additional user friendly features.

here's a short ruby loop for generating css:

```
(1..31).each do |i|
    p "#datepicker[data-date='#{i}'] .ui-datepicker-month:after { content: ' #{i},' }"
end
```

Comment: you could generate the loop using js too. It would be faster considering the js console is the fastest to access

Comment: actually, this will not work... so there are some days from the previous and next month that are clickable. so, for example the 1st of the next month might be clickable, say it's august 1st, well then "July 1, " will get displayed when it needs to be "August 1, ". adopting the setTimeout method. sorry to redact the answer accept.

Comment: ...and i find it quite amusing to see "July 32, 2016" http://jsfiddle.net/3b4g0s0v/6/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess with inserting your content into the datepicker element itself, why don't you just append your own div directly after each date picker, and then use that element to hold your content? Use insertAfter to add the element, and then later use next() to access it. Something like:

```
$("<div></div>").insertAfter(".ui-datepicker-month");

$("ui-datepicker-month").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $(this).next().html(dateText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` and moment.js to rewrite the entire html of `ui-datepicker-month`seems to be the best way here.

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardsharp/3b4g0s0v/9/